# How to resize UIButton depending on titleLabel sizel?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I use an array of 4 buttons and i want to resize the height of them depending on title size. Or resize characters of the title. What is the best and easiest? My buttons are `btn1` `btn2` `btn3` `btn4`

```
for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have a few solutions for you. Your question asks to resize the height of the button OR the characters of the titleLabel.

1. It's easier to adjust the size of the characters in the label. Here's the solution for that (replace `btn` with your buttons):

   ```
   btn.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
   btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
   btn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
   ```
2. Resizing the height of the buttons is a bit trickier. I've found a couple links to other answers that may work for you if you prefer this:

   - [UIButton that resizes to fit its titleLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259333/uibutton-that-resizes-to-fit-its-titlelabel)
   - [Resize UIbutton according to the text (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242709/resize-uibutton-according-to-the-text-swift)

Comment: `buttons` is an array of buttons!

Comment: Try it with `btn1`, `btn2`, etc.?

Comment: @AlexAndreadis updated my answer, hopefully this helps. let me know.